# Issue with UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a problem with my UIBarButton the button have a different color than my original image.

```
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "settings.png"), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSettingButton")
```

The color of the button is blue but my image is something like yellow !

Like this : [image]

It would be awesome if you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set image `UIImageRenderingMode` property:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "settings.png").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSettingButton")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This code :

```
var image : UIImage? = UIImage(named:"settings.png").imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Create a bar button property in your class     `var settingRightBarButton : UIBarButtonItem?`

then

```
let shareBarButtonImage = UIImage(named: "settings")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
self.settingRightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: shareBarButtonImage, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("didTapSettingButton"))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.settingRightBarButton
```

Add your images in `Images.xcassets`